# Android webview capture link clicks

Tags: android

The application i'm developing has a webview, i need to capture webview request click events(eg: click on a link, click on a button, click on a youtube video play button such as...)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This can be done

you have to set  a `WebViewClient` to your WebView. this is how to do that.

```
WebView webView;//make sure to initialize  
webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

WebViewClient webViewClient= new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url){
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView  view, String  url){
        if( url.equals("http://yoururl.com") ){
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't catch the event in my case. Is there any requirements on the xml part?

Comment: @Virthus the android webview is totally buggy and useless. A snippet works now but doesn't work a minute after. I don't know what does it want.

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView

Comment: To avoid multiple calls onPageFinished should be used instead of onLoadResource, right?

Answer (score 7):

use this code it's work for me

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
WebView myWebView  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.yourWebView);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
myWebView.loadUrl("yourLink");
```

but then don't forget to create a WebViewClient:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

     @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            return true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you handle links in your app, WebViewClient callbacks such as shouldOverrideUrlLoading and doUpdateVisitedHistory may not present consistent or correct values. In such cases, @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface is your friend. The idea is to write javascript click handlers (in the content) that pass information to your app through JavascriptInterface methods.

Here's an example of javascript for capturing the scrollY at the source of an internal jump to a #-anchor. Once in doUpdateVisitedHistory, it is generally too late to have this information available.

```
if (typeof AndroidCode != "undefined") { 
  var coll = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); 
  for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) { 
    var href = coll[i].getAttribute("href"); 
    if (href.indexOf("#") >= 0) { 
      coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() { 
        AndroidCode.reportInternalJump(); 
      }); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

AndroidCode is the name of the object that is declared through WebView.addJavascriptInterface.

Here's another useful example of this technique, though it is not directly related to links. It will report to OnPageFinished that the page is fully loaded (useful for instance when complex formatting is taking place and you don't want to setScrollY until lines have finished moving around).

```
if (typeof AndroidCode != "undefined") {
    AndroidCode.setLoadedStatus(false);

    window.onload = function () {
       AndroidCode.setLoadedStatus(true);
    }
}
```