Android Webview doesn't process <a href to trigger a deeplink
I want embedded webview from others apps process my appLink
example:
<p><a href="https://www.example.com/gizmos">Open Gizmos Page</a></p>
and in my app i already have the intent filter
`<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "https://www.example.com/gizmos" -->
<data
    android:scheme="https"
    android:host="www.example.com"
    android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
</intent-filter>`

note that this works perfectly in a chrome Tab. but embedded WebView have this functionality broken.
is this normal ?
and how can i make it work ?
I tried the example above on a chrome tab and it was working.
im expecting the webview to treat this hyper link similarly

This is expected. You need to override WebViewClient. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14137499/3286819 WebView is not a full web browser and has many limitations.

Webview is in third party apps and i have no access to it instance

Then your best bet probably is trying to add a target="_blank" to your link. The WebView handles differently links that are meant for the current WebView than links targeted for a new WebView, and maybe the third party app authors decided to handle that.
